# wordpress plugin for attaching galleries to posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is there a wordpress plug-in which enables you to attach image gallery to your news/post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Check out e.g. [**Top 10 WordPress Gallery Plugins**](http://techpp.com/2009/06/18/top-10-wordpress-gallery-plugins/)

Comment: @c0mrade you're welcome. If you're looking to do a lot of customization, be sure to take a look into the plugins' source code first. I have dealt with nggallery and the code was *quite* complicated with not much documentation. It's well possible that they're all that way, though :)